# Magento: how to echo metatitle in list.phtml

Tags: magento, echo

I want to echo the content of the metatitle under the price of each products in the grid view of the list.phmtl file. 
I originally used this:

```
   echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

But it prints the current page title under each product. I actually want to print the product's page title under each product. I am trying with this:

```
   echo $_product->getTitle();
```

but no luck. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `$_product->getMetaTitle()`, and ensure that the `meta_title` attribute  is  used in product listing.

Comment: I think that by default meta_title attribute has "Used in Product Listing" set to "No" and it should be set to "Yes" to have it on product list.